# Reducing 'apparent' page load times-how to load assets 'in the background'?

Tags: jquery, image, optimization, load

I have a site with several large jpgs used as background images

http://bitstream.ca/beta3/

There is a few second delay when the page loads before anything appears properly.

Can anyone suggets some methods, either using jQuery or otherwise, to intelligently load additional assets after the initial page load?

ie, pseudo logic would be
1 -load minimal assets for initial page display
2 -after #1 complete, load any additional assets needed for page functionality
3 -after #2 complete let the DOM know we are ready!

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are a couple optimizations you can do.

firstly, [sprite](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-image-sprites) and [optimize](http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/optimizing-images-for-web-35/) your images in order to make them as small and easy to load in one request as possible.

in terms of dynamic loading, there are a number of plugins you can use to lazy load images and other content which you don't need right away. check out:

- [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/)
- [Jquery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (which allows you to write your own little plugin pretty easily)
- [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: thanks, I'll look at the dynamic loading options. Sprite probably doesn't work well for full browser jpgs and they're already quite compressed.

Comment: also a good article on avoiding "FUBC" (flash of un-behaviored content) http://labjs.com/ LABjs & User-Experience

Comment: Head.js and lab.js are also options for deferred script loading, but not sure what the pros cons are of each